# React native state update is not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am using the package [react-native-background-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-downloader).
my state is initialize like this :

```
const [downloadFile, setDownloadFile] = useState({});
```

after i get data from api
i update my state:

```
setDownloadFile({
            thumbnail:
              'https://img.youtube.com/vi/J6rVaFzOEP8/maxresdefault.jpg',
            heading: 'Guide To Becoming A Self-Taught Software Developer',
            timing: 123,
            status: 'Staring ...',
          });
```

then i use the package to download the video from url

```
const ts = RNBackgroundDownloader.download({
            id: inputUrl,
            url: 'url too long to display',
            destination: `${RNBackgroundDownloader.directories.documents}/test.mp4`,
          });
          setTask(ts);
          ts.begin(async (res) => {
            await setDownloadFile({
              ...downloadFile,
              timing: res / 1024,
            });
            console.log('onbegin', downloadFile);
          });
          ts.progress(async (pr) => {
            await setDownloadFile({
              ...downloadFile,
              status: `Downloading... ${Math.round(pr * 100)}%`,
            });
            console.log('onProgress', downloadFile);
          });
          ts.done(async () => {
            await setDownloadFile({
              ...downloadFile,
              status: 'done',
            });
            console.log('onDone', downloadFile);
          });
```

my problem is that the state update in .begin() in timing variable is not taking place in .progress()

```
initially => timing:123,
.begin() => timing: res / 1024,
.progress() => timing:123 (as it was in first place);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`downloadFile` is a local const. It will never change, and that's not what `setDownloadFile` tries to do. The purpose of setting state is to tell the component to rerender. On that next render, a new local variable will be created, which gets the new value.

So every time you do:

```
setDownloadFile({
...downloadFile
 // etc
})
```

... you are making a copy of the `downloadFile` in this closure. Ie, the one that existed at the time you called RNBackgroundDownloader.download.

The simplest fix is to use the function version of setDownloadFile. You can pass a function to a state setter, and it will be called with the most recent state, and then you can base the new state on that. For example:

```
ts.progress((pr) => {
  setDownloadFile(previous => {
    return {
      ...previous, 
      status: `Downloading... ${Math.round(pr * 100)}%`,
    }
  });
});
```

I removed the async/await, because setting state does not return a promise so it served no purpose. I removed the logging too. If you want it, you'll need to put it inside the function.